# Multiple custom post type in URL

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I'm not sure how to handle this issue. We are developing an event website. So I've created of custom post type **Event**. Our customer can create x-number of events on their website. The URL of the event will be https://domain.com/event/event-name/

Each event will have an FAQ list with a separate FAQ detail page. So I've create another custom post type FAQ. The customer can add an FAQ item to the Event detail page. If a visitor clicks on the FAQ item, they go to the FAQ detail page https://domain.com/faq/faq-title/

**But** That FAQ item is specific for that Event. So the URL must be https://domain.com/event/event-name/faq/faq-title/

How can I manage that, keeping in mind that one FAQ item can be added on different Events?

Comment: It sounds like instead of creating FAQs as their own post type, they might be better created as reusable blocks. Then whenever you want to add them to an event, you just add it inside the event content. You can make them inside an accordion or show/hide style block so they don't take up as much room and expand when clicked, instead of taking people to a different URL.

Comment: One other option would be to open them within a modal. You can use the REST API to get each FAQ's content so the URL doesn't matter, it pops up in a modal above the event page and can be easily closed to view the others.

Comment: Okay yes that makes sense. So if I create a FAQ page for Event X. The URL will be domain.com/faq/event-x and on that page all the FAQ items will be shown with show/hide functionality, but they can't be opened on a different page.

Comment: Yes, that's another way of doing it - an event child page where the individual FAQs are reusable blocks, so you can edit them in a central place and they change on all the FAQ pages automatically.